# Eclipse XML Equivalent of "Organize Imports"

Tags: xml, eclipse

On my team, XML namespace declarations are constantly being cut and pasted resulting in a lot of unnecessary namespace declarations that are tedious to clean up.

Is there any way in Eclipse to **organize namespace declarations** on an XML file like you can with Java imports on a Java file?